DISM Error 800f081f Windows 11
Been trying to run this command all day on my Windows 11 23H2 machine to fix a few things.
DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth /Sources:wim:e:\sources\install.wim:1 /LimitAccess

Whenever I run it, I get error 800f081f and suggestion to use Source. The error states the source files could not be found.
I have also tried.
DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth /Sources:e:\sources /LimitAccess

Still get the same error. Am I missing something where DISM can't see the source files on repair for Windows 11 23H2.

Why are you providing it an external source? It’s not necessary. 800f081f is linked to the source not being accessible.

The correct command is: DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Restorehealth

@Ramhound because the computer is not connected to the internet.

The command I suggested does NOT use an online resource. /Online refers to the current online system.

Just to clarify, did you mount the Windows image and point to it, or did you extract the Windows image to a folder and point to it? I still suspect you are using the wrong syntax, and/or the source is not accessible, which is the reason you are getting the error code.

I think there is a typo in your command: you're trying to use the /Source option to specify a source for the files, but you wrote /Sources with an s.
Try:
DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth /Source:wim:E:\Sources\install.wim:1 /LimitAccess


But to be honest, there is a much simpler and more wholesome way to repair Windows system components than DISM. Try an in-place upgrade (see https://www.elevenforum.com/t/repair-install-windows-11-with-an-in-place-upgrade.418/, basically run the setup.exe from the mounted installation files and select to keep everything).
